# EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'

Tags: node.js, docker

Hello sir i am new to docker, i am using ubuntu budgie(linux) 20.04 my docker version is 
`Docker version 18.09.9, build 1752eb3`
i have install docker using snap package manager and the path is like this
`/snap/bin/docker.machine /snap/bin/docker.compose /snap/bin/docker /snap/bin/docker.help`
I have install nodejs and npm in my host machine form this link
[nodejs install link](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-node-js-10-11-12-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-via-apt-and-snap/)
I am learning docker by making a single nodejs express app with docker. Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts
USER node
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin
WORKDIR /home/node
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ['npm', 'start']
```

here is my app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world')
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('app is renning at 3000');
})
```

**When i start to build an image from this dockerfile i get this error**

```
internal/fs/utils.js:230
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:458:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:360:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1152:22)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
}
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --only=prod' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Please tell me how can i fix this. 
Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have attached two images to this question, where you were going to put the error text and the Dockerfile.  Can you delete these images and replace them with the actual text of those things?

Comment: please check now

Comment: Update to Docker version 19 as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990562/broken-docker-after-last-ubuntu-18-04-update

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i tried several solution but the only one how did work is to change docker version

```
docker-ce|5:18.09.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic|https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
docker-ce|18.06.3~ce~3-0~ubuntu|https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
docker-ce|18.06.2~ce~3-0~ubuntu|https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
```

i was using `5:19.03.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic`and i switched to `18.06.3~ce~3-0~ubuntu`

I kept the same Dockerfile config :

```
FROM node:10 
USER root 
WORKDIR /home/node/app 
COPY package.json . 
RUN npm install 

# Bundle app source COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8080  CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

## it returns :

```
Step 5/8 : RUN npm install
---> Running in 5b6cd0a9a7cd
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

> nodemon@1.19.4 postinstall /home/node/app/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
> https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN quiz-service@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN quiz-service@1.0.0 No repository field.

added 322 packages from 227 contributors and audited 323 packages in 21.573s

1 package is looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing intermediate container 5b6cd0a9a7cd
---> cc344027e126
Step 6/8 : COPY . /app
---> 10841d9cf0bf
Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 8080
```

you can check this link for more detail [on reinstalling docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion. Yes it is working. I have used the docker installation link you gave and it works. My docker version is now "Docker version 19.03.9, build 9d988398e7"

Answer (score 0):

This error originates from the fact, that your current user does not have enough permission to access the npm cli file.

Did you try the minimal Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /home/node
COPY . .
RUN npm install

CMD ['npm', 'start']
```

Does it work for you? If so, the problem in your Dockerfile, I assume in user `node` or you have some other script we don't see in OP.

Comment: it was all because of my docker version is old. Now i updated the docker version and now it is working. Now my current docker version is " "Docker version 19.03.9, build 9d988398e7""

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use yarn instead of node.

```
FROM node:10 
USER root 
WORKDIR /home/node/app 
COPY package.json . 
RUN yarn install
```