# Broken Docker after last Ubuntu 18.04 update

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

does anyone have problem with Docker after last Ubuntu update? Ive got 2 projects which I run by docker-compose in ubuntu18.04. Both projects worked fine, but after 0 changes in *.yml Im starting to get this error now.

```
 internal/fs/utils.js:230
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:461:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:363:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1166:22)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
}
ERROR: Service 'streaming-api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm config set unsafe-perm true' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I tried some commands to change permissions in Docker but nothing helps.

Comment: Can you add more detail to reproduce the problem like your docker-compose file and your Dockerfile ? Thanks!

Comment: ```version: '3'

services:
    diary-api:
        depends_on:
            - db
        build: ./src/diary-api
        image: diary-api:latest
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        restart: always

    db:
        image: postgres:alpine
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    
    adminer:
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8081:8080
```

Comment: ```FROM node:13.10.1-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run lint
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 9229
```

Comment: That sounds very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61967505/10008173); if it's different, can you edit your question to include a [mcve], including the code necessary to reproduce the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works again with Docker version 19 as stated in answer in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967505/eacces-permission-denied-open-usr-local-lib-node-modules-npm-bin-npm-cli-js) of David. The answer is from [oussama faleh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12948029/oussama-faleh).

Here my steps to install docker version 19 on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
sudo apt-get install     apt-transport-https     ca-certificates     curl     gnupg-agent     software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
sudo add-apt-repository    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
docker -v
```